# Java: Retrieve working directory of current process builder

Tags: java, process, processbuilder, working-directory

I am running a java application (app1) that runs multiple instances of another java application (app2) in parallel using ProcessBuilder and Fixed Thread Pool with the following code:

```
futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for (int i=0; i<cnt;i++)
{
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();   
builder.command("java","app2");  //I set the class path in the real code
builder.directory(new File("/Users/Evan/Documents/workspace/MyProj/ins_"+i));
builder.inheritIO();
ProcessRunner pr=new ProcessRunner (builder);  
futures.add(executor.submit(pr));
}
```

Each run of app2 has different working directory (the value of i in the folder ins_i is different for each run).  The code works, but now in app2, I want to read a file from the working directory of the current process (i.e. /Users/Evan/Documents/workspace/MyProj/ins_"+i).  So in app2 code I need a statement that let me know the directory of the current process builder (basically the value of i in "/Users/Evan/Documents/workspace/MyProj/ins_"+i).
I tried this statement:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

and it did not work because it retrieved "/Users/Evan/Documents/workspace/MyProj"

Thank you and I appreciate any help

Comment: What is `ProcessRunner`? What does it actually do when it runs?

Answer (score 0):

> but now in app2, I want to read a file from the working directory of the current process

If you know the filename you want to read from within the working directory of app2, you can just create a File object, passing the file name of the file you wish to read. The parent folder defaults to the current working directory (which is defined by the ProcessBuilder)

```
File myFile = new File("FileToRead");
//read from myFile using FileInputStream
```